# Create an redirect in htacces

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm kind of new to creating redirects and I need some help with this matter.

I'm trying to redirect a link that looks like `http://marpic.pt/query_piscinas.php?modelo=Corredor%20Nata%E7%E3o`

And I want to redirect to `http://marpic.pt/`

I tried with the following code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} modelo=Corredor%20Nata%E7%E3o
RewriteRule ^query_piscinas\.php$ /$ [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does not work mean? Isn't it redirecting? Does Apache crash? Something else? Unrelated, but *never* test with [`R=301`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)!

Comment: Hi olaf

Thank you for your reply. It doesn't redirect

Comment: Then maybe it's the percent encoding. Does it work, when you test with just `modelo=Corredor`

Comment: I the case i showed thats a problem of enconding on the link. I tried with others that dont have that problem but it still doesnt work

Comment: Another problem might be `/$`, because there's no regular expression in the substitution. Apart from that, you must look into Apache's error logs.

Comment: I understood what the problem was. 
Earlier i added an 301 redirect for /query_piscinas.php

redirect 301 /query_piscinas.php /piscinas/

And this was what stopping the redirect i was talking but now i need a solution for this one